# Restsharp - Deserialize xml to list where element tag contains unique id

Tags: c#, rest, deserialization, restsharp

I am consuming a Rest-based service (CRM system called Solve360) and for example I am grabbing a list of contacts here is a snippet what I receive from the server:

```
<response>
 <id99623996>
  <id>99623996</id>
  <name>Aaron</name>
  <typeid>1</typeid>
  <parentid>98830114</parentid>
  <parentcn>CC</parentcn>
  <flagged/>
  <created>2014-01-03T17:10:47+00:00</created>
  <viewed>2014-01-14T20:35:26+00:00</viewed>
  <updated>2014-01-03T17:11:13+00:00</updated>
 </id99623996>
 <id99624297>
  <id>99624297</id>
  <name>Abigail </name>
  <typeid>1</typeid>
  <parentid>98830114</parentid>
  <parentcn>CC</parentcn>
  <flagged/>
  <created>2014-01-03T17:11:01+00:00</created>
  <viewed>2014-01-03T17:11:01+00:00</viewed>
  <updated>2014-01-03T17:11:13+00:00</updated>
 </id99624297>
</response>
```

So here is my c# code using latest Restsharp:

```
public T ExecuteSerializedCommand<T>(string resourceLoc, string method, Dictionary<string, string> parameters) where T : new() {
var request = BuildRestRequest(resourceLoc, method, parameters);
request.RootElement = "Response";
var response = RestSharpObj.Execute<T>(request);
if (response.ErrorException != null) {
    const string message = "Error retrieving response.  Check inner details for more info.";
    var rsMessage = new ApplicationException(message, response.ErrorException);
    throw rsMessage;
}
    return response.Data;
}
```

And Here is the calling code:

```
public List<Contact> GeContacts() {
    return ExecuteSerializedCommand<List<Contact>>(ITEM_CONTACTS, RESTVERB_GET, new  Dictionary<string, string>());
}
```

Oh and my class Contact:

```
public class Contact {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int typeid { get; set; }
    public int parentid { get; set; }
    public string parentcn { get; set; }
    public string flagged { get; set; }
    public DateTime created { get; set; }
    public DateTime viewed { get; set; }
    public DateTime updated { get; set; }
}
```

So my final deserialized response is null.
Any suggestions are appreciated. I think the problem is in the xml tag that contains the id number. Not sure how to handle that with Restsharp.

Comment: It looks to me, that your root element ("<response>") needs a child element that represents the list. Children of that element then should be the Contact elements. Also, how should RestSharp know that "<id*RandomNumber*>" is a Contact element?

Comment: However, if you can't change the XML structure (because of the CRM system), you might try to process the XML manually to get the content of the <id*> elements, which you could then deserialize into Contact instances using RestSharp.

Comment: No I cannot change the output from the CRM system. I was hoping that I would not have to write manual deserializers for every element I want to retrieve. Could you elaborate on how I would pass those elements back to RestSharp once I handled the list as you suggest? Thanks.

Comment: You would implement your own XML deserializer used by RestSharp in which you deal with your XML structure, as you said. Unfortunately i don't know how to do that for XML in RestSharp. My experience is only with JSON deserialization using Json.NET (but RestSharp has abandoned Json.NET anyway) so i really don't know how to do it in detail. Sorry :(